# ruby regular expression not working with match

Tags: ruby, regex

```
text = "I fixed bug #1234 and #7895 "
regex = /#(\d*)/
m = regex.match(text)
puts m.inspect #<MatchData "#1234" "1234">
```

In the above case why I am not seeing 7895? What's the correct solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regexps only match the first occurrence (or not at all, of course). `#(\d*)` matches `#1234` first, so that piece of text is returned.

If you want multiple matches, i.e., you want to *search* a string, use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812) or something similar.

Comment: Also, you should be using #(\d+) not \d* - The star is for zero or more occurrences and I don't think you want the string 'I fixed bug #invalid' to match.